# How to use navigation stack in simulation using .dae and rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use and learn navigation stack,
I'd like to simulate 2D navigation
(path planning and collision avoidance)
using a robot model(e.g. PR2.dae) and rviz.

Are there any tutorials for that?
What are good practices for learning how to use navigation stack?

ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator gave me some tutorials
but it uses Gazebo.
If possible, I'd like to use only rviz to make the simulation simple.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35769/how-to-use-navigation-stack-in-simulation-using-.dae-and-rviz/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz is not a simulator, but a visualization tool. That means whether you run in simulation or on the real robot, you can use RViz just the same. If you want to try 2D navigation, you either need a simulator or a real robot in addition to RViz.

If you want something simpler than Gazebo, you might want to use [stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage). There is a package that shows how to use the navigation stack in stage [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3